# USB OTG on OnePlus 2 phone not working, yet

Tags: usb-on-the-go, oneplus-two

As I understand it I HAVE to use the original USB OTG adapter from OnePlus before I can make use of the OTG functionality on my OnePlus 2.

But what happens if I connect a USB OTG Y-cable (powered from a USB charger) to the original OnePlus 2 OTG adapter?

This is what I would like to achieve - I'm not sure if the cable is supposed to be used in this manner

[image]

**[EDIT_1]**
Normally you would just plug the OTG cable into your phone and then (hopefully) it would work - But with the OnePlus 2 phone you have to use OnePlus' original OTG adapter in order to make OTG work (That's what I have read anyway) - I'm just worried that connecting 2 OTG items (cable and adapter) might cause problems.
If I could just find a cable like the one pictured above that ISN'T an OTG cable, then I don't think there would be a problem.

[USB Micro-B] to [USB-A female] with a [USB-A male] for extra power.

Hopefully the above would alow me to attach almost any device to my phone and I wouldn't have to worry about the phones power being drained in no time.

I would also like to keep the amount of adapters, converters and cables to a minimum.

**[EDIT_2]**
Connecting the above USB OTG power cable and/or a regular USB (USB Micro-B to USB-A Female) cable to the OnePlus 2 adapter does nothing. The USB OTG Power cable DOES charge the phone though. I have now ordered two original OnePlus OTG cables from eBay...
Let's see how that plays out...

**[EDIT_3]**
One of the original OnePlus cables arrived today - It's supposed to be for the OnePlus 1, but I hoped it would work with the OnePlus 2 adapter.

Still no dice...

**[EDIT_4]**
Better late than never (sorry)...
None of the adapters that I have tried works. Maybe I received a FAKE OnePlus 2 adapter, I don't know.
I officially give up trying to make it work.

[image]

Does everything in this "adapter chain" have to support USB OTG ??

Comment: See this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/172985/131553) and in particular where I have linked the problems with one plus. My guess is that is what caused your original problem and what you received were fakes or incompatible

Comment: I think you are right about the adapters/cables being fake or incompatible.

Comment: Only way to confirm is to get hold of truly original ones but then you have given up :)

Comment: I have given up :)