# Can a faulty Micro-USB cable cause damage to your device?

Tags: usb, charging

Hardware damage caused by USB Type-C cables by drawing too much power has been widely reported:

- https://www.howtogeek.com/240777/watch-out-how-to-buy-a-usb-type-c-cable-that-wont-damage-your-devices/
- http://www.theverge.com/2016/2/4/10916264/usb-c-russian-roulette-power-cords
- http://www.pcworld.com/article/3002064/computers-accessories/beware-bad-usb-c-cables-google-engineer-warnswhile-naming-names.html
- http://gizmodo.com/cheap-usb-c-cables-could-kill-your-phone-or-laptop-1757115350
- http://www.androidcentral.com/usb-c-problem-isnt-going-away-anytime-soon

Is Micro-USB affected?

Answer (score 2):

Root of the problem is **non adherence to standards** and **not** type C as a class of faulty cables.

The damage caused specifically relates to :

- *poor adherence of standards* to the extent of being non standard
- Using a [wrongly rated resistor by one plus](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/11/oneplus-admits-that-its-selling-dodgy-usb-type-c-cables-and-adapters/)
  in their products, which fried other devices connected to such cables

Benson Leung is a Google Engineer who carries out extensive testing of practically anything related to type C, which you can read on [his Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/collection/s0Inv)

If you use any *non standard product*, you always run the risk of damage / poor performance. This is equally true of micro USB cables, though I haven't come across such bad press for micro USB ( barring chargers of spurious quality)

Answer (score 2):

USB-C cables are "intelligent" (own chip in the cable) and the USB-C PowerDelivery (PD) standard allows higher voltages for loading. In USB-C the power supply, the cable and the phone have to agree on who is the source, who the sink and how much power in what voltage will be delivered. This is very complex with the result that there is a non-negligible chance that something goes wrong or event extremely goes wrong (damages something).

Micro USB cables are "dumb": They have no no chip. Hence the only effect an Micro USB cable can have is that it is too thin and therefore reduces the electrical flow, delaying the charging process.

However theoretically you can still damage your phone if you use a non-charger that is not backward compatible. But in this case the cable will be innocent.